# Microsoft Graph upload image

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, put

I am trying to make a PUT request to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value`
with Microsoft Graph Explorer

But I get an Internal error 500. Am i doing something wrong or is there a problem with the Graph API

```
    {
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorInternalServerError",
        "message": "An internal server error occurred. The operation failed., The file you chose isn't an image. Please choose a different file.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "60c801ff-7d83-47a1-9d38-c01a4769ec1b",
            "date": "2018-08-08T09:28:18"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the current state you can't upload binary files with Microsoft Graph Explorer. Use Postman to upload binary files. Make a PUT request with "User.ReadWrite" as permission and Content-Type: Image/Jpeg.